# GLSL optimization by wrapping tris?

Tags: opengl, optimization, rendering

So I'm considering two different approaches to render objects in OpenGL.
First approach:
Use the TRIANGLE_STRIP setting with the idea of compressing the amount of vertex data written into the buffer every render. The drawback here is that normals have to be calculated on the shaders, instead of being provided at initialization.

Second approach:
Use the regular old triangle draw method, which allows most if not all vertex data, including normals, to be provided at initialization. The drawback here is that vertex data can get repetitive when writing to the buffer, especially when multiple triangles share a single vertex.

So my question is, which method is preferable? And is there another way that improves on both that I'm not thinking of? I'm new to the OpenGL scene, so take it easy on me. Thanks!

Comment: there are also indices ...

Comment: True. But with indices, you would still need to duplicate vertices in the buffer with separate normals data

Comment: I use duplicated vertex positions with different normals with no problem. You shouldn't worry about it unless you identify a rendering bottleneck from this. Instead, you should focus on making sure you `glBufferX` occur as infrequently as possible.

Comment: glBufferX? Is this a literal term or a reference?